# Confusion in Rx Swift syntax

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactive

I'm reading the Rx-Reactive Programming books by raywenderlich and I am confused by this syntax of Rx Swift:

```
extension PHPhotoLibrary {
    static var authorized: Observable<Bool> {
        return Observable.create({ observer in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if authorizationStatus() == .authorized {
                    observer.onNext(true)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                } else {
                    observer.onNext(false)
                    requestAuthorization({ newStatus in
                        observer.onNext(newStatus == .authorized)
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    })
                }
            }

            return Disposables.create()
        })
    }
}
```

Why does the code have two `return` statements? Can somebody explain me why we need 2 return statement in the code?

Answer (score 7):

If you format the code better, you will see that the first *return* belongs to *static var authorized*, and the other to the observable. It has nothing to do with RxSwift, just normal Swift syntax.

```swift
extension PHPhotoLibrary {
    static var authorized: Observable<Bool> {

        return Observable.create({ observer in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if authorizationStatus() == .authorized {
                    observer.onNext(true)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                } else {
                    observer.onNext(false)
                    requestAuthorization({ newStatus in
                        observer.onNext(newStatus == .authorized)
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    })
                }
            }

            return Disposables.create()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please answer this question of mine?